# How to create a category attribute to list all the searchable attributes of products?

Tags: magento-1, category-attribute

I want to list all the searchable product attributes in a multiselect as category attribute.

Please see the attached screenshot.

[image]

```
 <?php
 /**
  * @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup $installer
  */
 $this->startSetup();
 if (!$this->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'content_after_products')) {
     $this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'content_after_products', array(
         'group'                    => 'General Information',
         'input'                    => 'textarea',
         'type'                     => 'text',
         'label'                    => 'Content After Products',
         'backend'                  => '',
         'visible'                  => true,
         'required'                 => false,
         'wysiwyg_enabled'          => true,
         'visible_on_front'         => true,
         'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
         'global'                   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
     ));
 }
 $this->endSetup()
```

Answer (score 3):

***For getting Search attribute Collection.You can try below  collection code:***

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
            ->addVisibleFilter()->addFieldToFilter('is_searchable',1);
```

**Every Multiple Select attribute have**

- *Source model:* `Backend Model is used for database operations relating to an attribute.`
- *backend model :* `Source Model is used to display pre-existing data for an attribute. Either through configuration files or through
  database table`.

  See more at: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/06/10/magento-eav-concepts/#sthash.mtsHZRdt.dpuf

So for this ,you should *create Source model & backend model*.
Also *input type should be multiselect*.

```
'input'                      => 'multiselect',
'source'                     => '[Model_Prefix]/category_attribute_source_search',
'backend'                     => '[Model_Prefix]/category_attribute_backend_search',
```

**Installer may be like this:**

```
$installer=$this;
$installer->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'content_after_products', array(
        'type'                       => 'text',
        'label'                      => 'Content After Products',
        'input'                      => 'multiselect',
        'source'                     => '[Module_Prefix]/category_attribute_source_search',
        'backend'                     => '[Module_Prefix]/category_attribute_backend_search',
        'required'      => false,
        'sort_order'                 => 40,
        'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group'                      => 'Display Settings',
    ));
$installer->endSetup();
```

**Source Model class:**

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Category_Attribute_Source_Search
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Retrieve All options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        /* Get Search Attribute Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
            ->addVisibleFilter()->addFieldToFilter('is_searchable',1);
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            foreach ($collection as $attribute) {
                $this->_options[] = array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__($attribute['frontend_label']),
                    'value' => $attribute['attribute_code']
                );
            }
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

**Backend module Name:**

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Search
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Validate process
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $object
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate($object)
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Before Attribute Save Process
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $object
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Attribute_Backend_Sortby
     */
    public function beforeSave($object) {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        if ($attributeCode == 'content_after_products') {
            $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
            if (!is_array($data)) {
                $data = array();
            }
            $object->setData($attributeCode, join(',', $data));
        }
        if (is_null($object->getData($attributeCode))) {
            $object->setData($attributeCode, false);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function afterLoad($object) {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        if ($attributeCode == 'content_after_products') {
            $data = $object->getData($attributeCode);
            if ($data) {
                $object->setData($attributeCode, explode(',', $data));
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Full module available at [github](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento-stackexchange/tree/master/Category%20multi%20Select%20attribute/app) 
[image]